# Copy a dictionary with int List <int, List<int>> by value

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary with int keys, and int Lists as values. How can I copy this by value?

I did the following, but it copies the List part by reference:

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> d2 = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>(d1);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `ToDictionary` to copy the dictionary and `ToList` to copy lists:

```
var dNew = d1.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.ToList());
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use linq:

```
var d2 = d1.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => new List<int>(y.Value));
```

[See a live demo on rextester](http://rextester.com/TPSBU30386)

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Comment: Dear downvoter: The code I've shown does exactly what the OP requested. Care to explain why do you think my answer is not useful?

Comment: @ZoharPeled The guy has simply downvoted all of the answers and I doubt he cares to explain anything to us. It will be fair though if I'll upvote your answer to balance things a little.

Comment: @Fabjan thanks! I know asking for downvoters to explain their vote is usually just a waist of time, but sometimes, the person that downvoted (or even another person) can shed some lite on the downvote reason. I know I've had a few comments explaining why my answer was downvoted - some of them actually helped me learn new things...